# Set VS 2017's Task List's (Token List) back to defaults?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017
I edited existing Task List Tokens via the Tools | Options | Environment | Task List dialog
I deleted the (HACK) and (UnresolvedMergeConflict) Tokens and Added new Tokens.

My question is . . . Is there a way to set the Task List's (Token List) back to defaults? I want to reset the Tokens List because some of my custom Tokens (Tokens I made myself) are no longer in the Options | Environment | Task List dialog. The problematic custom Tokens are displayed in the Task List window but not in the Options | Environment | Task List dialog. My custom Token List, has been corrupted or is messed up and I cannot fix it from the Task List dialog.

The only option I can see are 1 ) reset the list to defaults or 2 ) identify the where the (Task List / Token List) is stored so I can edit that file (if it's in an editable file) and fix my Token List problem. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem, by the way I had added a custom Token to my Task List = (**Todo Later**) I believe this custom (**Todo Later**) Token may have been causing the oddities with my Task List dialog not showing it.

Anyway from within the VS 2017 IDE I navigated the menus `Tools | Import Export Settings`...  `All Settings | Options | Environment | Task List`.  Then *exported the **Task List*** item only. I did this from a session of VS 2017 that did not have the issues described. Then I *Imported* that file *into* the *Visual Studio* session that I had this issue with.  This seems to have fix the problem.